# Install QGIS with ECW support conda-forge

Tags: qgis, gdal, ecw, anaconda, conda

How can I add ECW support to QGIS instaleld in conda environment?

conda 23.3.1
qgis 3.30.3-'s-Hertogenbosch
Windows 10

Comment: You can't (yet) unless you build the ECW gdal driver plugin from source. conda-forge GDAL doesn't provide the ECW driver. https://github.com/conda-forge/gdal-feedstock/issues/697